# How to take back some files from a commit?

Tags: git

Say, you've commited all of your files but really meant some.

```
git commit -am "commit1"

# should've been instead
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "commit1"
```

How can I remove some files from a commit? I don't want to get rid of the changes, I just want this time not commit all the files.

Comment: use `git commit --amend` -- it will modify your last commit

Comment: @mariusm, but it modifies only the message?

Comment: it will modify entire commit, i.e. it will append all your modifications, see the manual by `git commit --help`.

Comment: if you want to remove files from the last commit then do `git rm fileX` and then `git commit --amend`.

Comment: note that this is fine as long as you have not `push`ed your changes to another repository, if you have, you might get in trouble.

Comment: Do a new commit with your fixes and merge them together, if you did not push anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
git reset HEAD^
git add <your files>
git commit
```

Explanation:
`git reset` in that context changes what your branch points to, without touching the files in your repository.
`HEAD^` points to the commit just before the one you are looking at, so `reset HEAD^` will "undo" the commit by making the branch point to the commit just before in the commit history.

Since you keep your files, you can re-add them as needed.

---

Side note: while you point the branch to the previous commit, your current commit becomes "orphan", and will be hard to find again. You can find its commit ID in the reflog with `git reflog`, and then display it with `git show <ID>` or similar. You could also create a new tag or branch before the `reset` operation. Generally speaking with git, you can't lose your data as long as you committed it at some point.

---

What @mariusm said works quite well too: you can just revert the unwanted file to a previous state with `git checkout HEAD^ -- my-file.txt` (careful, that will overwrite the current version) and commit it with `git add my-file.txt; git commit --amend`. It might be more complicated depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps clear to anyone, but not me: if you are in a new branch and you want to get a step back, you have to reset to the last commit that was right before your new commit. That seemed a bit strange to me at first, to go back to a commit that was "before your work". Yet, if you do so, `Head^` is doing something else: you drop your commit (save the commit message!) and still have your work on top of the last commit that is left over from the past, and you will also still have the chosen files checked that you newly commited. It is just how it was before you commited, that easy.

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine I added an explanation, I hope it's clearer. You can find the previous commit message in the `reflog` if you need it, in any case. (the reflog is kind of the "undo history" of git; more accurately, it's the history of commits you've viewed, or what HEAD has been pointing to recently). The previous commit won't be lost before the next garbage collection, which very rarely happens (months or years usually, depending on activity).

Comment: `Since you keep your files, you can re-add them as needed.`: yes, you keep your files, and no, you do not need to re-add them, they are already staged. You go back to that moment right before you git commited your work, thus, not fully back to the old commit itself, but to "old commit + your work + all of the staged files you have commited").

Answer (score 1):

if you have not `push`ed your commit then just do the stuff you want to to look like, add the modifications with `git add` or `git rm` and then do `git commit --amend` (you may want to change the message, but that is another option to this command)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to take some file from commit `<A>`, then you can:

```
git checkout <A> path/to/the/file.txt
git commit --amend
```

Typically, when you have committed the file by mistake you want to check it out from the previous commit:

```
git checkout HEAD^ path/to/the/file.txt
git commit --amend
```